Unbiased estimator for sample mean or variance using non-uniform sampling
Wikipedia mentions that given as input n iid samples $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$, the unbiased sample variance is given as $\frac{1}{(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\mu)^2$, where $\mu$ denotes the sample mean.
I was wondering whether similar unbiased estimators are known for sample mean or sample variance when we sample elements using non-uniform or weighted sampling.
Any comments or references are appreciated.

Can you give an example of "non-uniform or weighted sampling"?  Incidentally, that is not the only unbiased estimator of variance: $\frac12(Y_n-Y_1)^2$ is an example of another unbiased estimator (which is likely in some sense to be worse).

One example of weighted sampling would be proportional sampling, in which elements have weights and an element is sampled with probability proportional to its weight. Assuming you can sample following such a distribution, what would be a good estimate for the variance of the weights?
